# Feasible with my Problem case using DAX Column Function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new with DAX Column Function would like to ask if in my case is feasible with DAX Formula.

Please note the following:
1/Higher Number Version means Latest Version
2/If the latest version of ID Column is TRUE set the Older version as TRUE else FALSE for both
Version.
3.My ID Column is my identifier.

Let's Assume Today to Process Sample Data Day 1

***Sample Data Day 1***

```
Input Data              
ID  Version For Monitoring      
123ABC  5   TRUE        
456DEF  5   FALSE       
789GHI  5   TRUE        
123ABC  4   FALSE       
456DEF  4   TRUE        
789GHI  4   FALSE
```

[image]

Let's Assume the expected data to process for the next day is like this sample
***Sample Data Day 2***

```
Input Data              
ID  Version For Monitoring      
123ABC  5   TRUE        
456DEF  5   FALSE       
789GHI  5   TRUE        
123ABC  4   FALSE       
456DEF  4   TRUE        
789GHI  4   FALSE       
123ABC  6   FALSE       
456DEF  6   TRUE        
789GHI  6   FALSE
```

[image]

***Day 1 Sample Output
Output Data***

```
ID  Version For Monitoring  Revised For Monitoring
123ABC  5   TRUE    TRUE
456DEF  5   FALSE   FALSE
789GHI  5   TRUE    TRUE
123ABC  4   FALSE   TRUE
456DEF  4   TRUE    FALSE
789GHI  4   FALSE   TRUE
```

[image]

***Day 2 Sample Output
Output Data

Output Data***

```
ID  Version For Monitoring  Revised For Monitoring
123ABC  5   TRUE    FALSE
456DEF  5   FALSE   TRUE
789GHI  5   TRUE    FALSE
123ABC  6   FALSE   FALSE
456DEF  6   TRUE    TRUE
789GHI  6   FALSE   FALSE
123ABC  4   FALSE   FALSE
456DEF  4   TRUE    TRUE
789GHI  4   FALSE   FALSE
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *ask if in my case is feasible with DAX Formula.* ... I believe it is possible with DAX.  For me, it would be easier to solve using Power Query M Code.